# How to get the longest user name? (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a list of users ID, and I want to find the user with the longest name.
But when I use `bot.get_user(id)` it returns None.
I checked the ID, it is valid and does correspond to a user on the server.
Code:

```
            for score in scores:
                bad_chars = "<@!>"
                for letter in score:
                    if letter in bad_letters:
                        score = score.replace(letter, "")

                print(score)
                print(bot.get_user(int(score.strip("<@! >"))))
                member_len = bot.get_user(int(score.strip("<@ >")))

                if member_len:
                    print(len(member_len.name))
                    if len(member_len.name) > score_len:
                        score_len = len(member_len.name)

            print(score_len)
```

Comment: // , Can you edit your answer to add some links to the docs or other research you've (presumably) already done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new version of discord.py(1.5.x), there're some updates about `Intents`. Intents are similar to permissions, you have to define Intents to get channels, members and some events etc. You have to define it before defining the `client = discord.Bot(prefix='')`.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)
```

If you want to get more information about Intents, you can look at the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents).